# Identify the subject, object and verb

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, subjects, objects

In the sentence below I want to confirm whether I have correctly identified the subject, object and the verb (It's a sentence I made up as an example and hope it's correct, and if not please correct it too).

> He wants them to be go away from the team.

Subject: He
Verb: Wants
Object: Team or Them?

Does "go away" also a verb in here? What kind of a work "Them" in this context?

Comment: "He wants them to [leave/quit/resign from] the team" is natural, idiomatic native-speaker English. "Go away" is understandable but not normal.

Comment: @BillFranke: Unless _them_ refers to someone not on the team. For example, a coach might say (referring to a group of reporters): _I want them to go away from the team_ (although, in that context,  I think _get away_ might be better than _go away_).

Comment: @J.R.: You've made a good point. I'd say "stay away", however, but, yes, _get away_ sounds better than _go away_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence as it stands is ungrammatical, because you can’t precede the plain form of the verb (*go*) with *to be*. Even rewritten as *He wants them to go away from the team*, it is still unsatisfactory, because the verb normally used in such a context is *leave*.

In a suitably amended sentence, there are two clauses, the finite, *He wants them*, and the non-finite, *to leave the team*, but one cannot occur without the other. In the first clause, *he* is the subject, *wants* is the verb and *them* is the object. The entire second clause is a non-finite complement clause, functioning as the object predicative of the main clause. *Them* is both the object of *wants* and the implied subject of *to leave*, and *the team* is the object of *leave*.

Comment: you mean  wants is the verb

Comment: Thanks. by the way why you cant use go after verb be. If we want to use is it should be like "be gone". Also what tense does "be gone" fall in to?

Comment: @Harshana: _Gone_ is the past participle of _go_, not the plain form.

Comment: i mean "be gone" all together

Comment: @Harshana: _Be gone_ is a somewhat archaic expression of dismissal. _He wants them to be gone_ is certainly possible, but _He wants them to be go_ is not.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct with the subject and the verb. The object is them, not 'the team' which is part of a new clause due to the word 'to'. 'Go away from the team' describes the state of 'them'. The correct sentence is "He wants them to go away from the team". You don't need 'be', although you could also say "He wants them to be gone from the team".